# Wordpress Pagination in Custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the following code to generate pagination on my wordpress pages:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>
```

Notice `'format' => '?paged=%#%'`. According to the Codex there'd be a different format for pretty links i.e. [codex says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

> **format**
>   (string) (optional) Used for Pagination structure. The default value is `'?page=%#%'`, If using pretty permalinks this would be `'/page/%#%'`, where the `'%#%'` is replaced by the page number.
>   Default: `'?page=%#%'`

What I'm getting is, I'd have to change the php code in my theme file whenever I change the permalinks format. That'd be pretty much tedious, so Is there any way that I can make my pagination adapt itself to the permalink style i.e. it doesn't break if I change the permalinks style to pretty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug up a little something in the Wordpress Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)

**using_mod_rewrite_permalinks** - Returns true your blog is using "pretty" permalinks via mod_rewrite.

So try this

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
global $wp_rewrite;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

if( $wp_rewrite->using_mod_rewrite_permalinks() ) {
    myformat = '/page/%#%';
} else {
    myformat = '?page=%#%';
}

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => myformat,
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```